Managed package -- error in field names in decisions due to namespace prefix
I run into a problem after deploying a package with a namespace. Found an error in a decision within a record-triggered flow.

The field "BC_Poder__c" should have received the namespace prefix in the destination org, but it didn't. I found it happens in every decision component around every flow in the package.
Yes I can fix the flow by changing the field in the resource to:
{!$Record.R2C2_002__BC_Poder__c}
Where the namespace prefix is "R2C2_002__", but I wouldn't expect this to be an error to be manually fixed for all flows (and who knows what else) every time I install the package in a brand new org.
Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Is it a 1GP or 2GP?

Flows have very brittle and non-standard namespace handling; the packaged flow must reference the (objects, settings and) fields (etc.) with the namespace prefix, otherwise stuff gets broken (like you found). Even then, we have an open support case around packaging translations where we have reference to a namespaced custom setting that goes wrong when we try to package the flow.

It's a Managed 1GP package I'm trying to build.

To Phil: the flow is not going to work in the source org. Should I consider editing each individual flow XML file?

This has been an issue for past couple of years. I don't think any element truly supports namespaces perfectly in Flows. It's been a pain, since for past year or so, Salesforce was too keen on pushing Flows for everything but this thing never got fixed. There are at least 3 Known Issues for this - https://issues.salesforce.com/#q=flow%20namespace (Unable to post the individual links, as comment space is limited)

Make sure that the "source org" is a namespaced scratch org - make sure you adopt SFDX working practices with version control and scratch orgs.

As far as I know (and I'm not even sure), I should "upload" the package from the source to the scratch org and then "download" from the scratch to build the managed package. This should fix the error I guess...

Question: should I fix the errors in the scratch org before pulling it from the source (DX)?
